# How to fix my code to remove the spaces in a string?

Tags: c++, c++14

So I am trying to remove spaces from a string but if I input for example "hello world" it only return "hello" and not "helloworld". I am not sure why it does this.

```
string removeSpaces(string str)
{
    str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "Enter word: ";
    std::cin >> input;

    input = removeSpaces(input);
    std::cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not with the function (as far as I can see). It's with the way you read the input.

`std::cin >> input` will read until a white space. So `input` will be "Hello".

To read the whole line use

```
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Comment: @Jello sure. If you've got a satisfactory answer make sure to mark it as "Accepted" so that your question doesn't stay opened.

Comment: @Jello As above

Answer (score 0):

Because `std::cin >> input` reads only "hello".